# NSLog inside variable arguments function

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nslog, variadic-functions

I do not have clear idea about objective c variable argument function. I want to write a function which will take a nlsog type parameter but sometime I shall use NSLog inside that function. How can I do that?

```
-(void) printStatus:(NSString*)status, ...
{
    // I want use use NSLog with all these parameter here.

    // some gui logging also happens here
}
```

Calls will be like this,

```
[self printStatus:@"status"];
```

or

```
[self printStatus:@"Staus: %@", someObject];
```

Instead of using NSLog, I want to use printStatus. When I need to switch the console logging to a GUI logging, I can do it only changing to the printStatus function, not changing all places inside my code.

Or use DLog as I am using here,

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#    define DLog(...) /* */
#endif
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to work with C's varargs types and the `NSLogv` macro:

```
-(void)printStatus:(NSString*)status, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, status);
    NSLogv(status, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

This assumes the `status` argument is a format string followed by its arguments.

If you want to create an `NSString` from the format string and arguments (for updating your GUI) you can do this in addition to `NSLogv`:

```
NSLogv(status, args);
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:status arguments:args];
// ... log to GUI
```

Comment: thanks. but I was using a DLog macro, where I was using NSLog. Is there any way to use NSLog? #ifdef DEBUG
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#    define DLog(...) /* */
#endif

Comment: The only way to pass-through variable arguments in functions/methods is using a `va_list`. This is why most libraries will offer a `*v` alternative which accepts a `va_list`. You should therefore create a `DLogv` which calls `NSLogv`, and forward the arguments to that.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of the 2nd case. But I was not sure of the 1st case. Since in when creating the string in the 2nd case, I have to call the va_start(args, status), otherwise args is not populated to use with the NSString. Not it?

Comment: In both the `NSLogv` and `NSString` examples you must do the `va_list`/`va_start` stuff.

Comment: seems calling va_list and va_start fulfill my purpose. But is it needed to vall va_end?

Comment: Yes. This will clean up memory and resources that `va_start` initializes.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, for interested people, here is my final version of logging ...

```
-(void) printStatus:(NSString*)status, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, status);
    va_end(args);
    NSString * str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:status arguments:args];
    DLog(@"%@", str);
    self.statusTextView.text = [_statusTextView.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n%@",str];
    [str release];
}
```

`DLog` is defined in my `Prefix.pch` file,

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#    define DLog(...) /* */
#endif
```

Comment: "// invoke this method on the main thread instead" This won't work. You are losing all the varargs arguments, and the function will crash on the main thread if it expects any of those arguments

Comment: thanks. I'v modified the code. But I need to make it thread friendly too.

Answer (score -2):

I am not able to understand the question exactly. As I understood you can use formated string

```
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"this is string %@",@"String"];
```

Comment: Instead of using NSLog, I want to use printStatus. When I need to switch the console logging to a GUI logging, I can do it only changing to the printStatus function, not changing all places inside my code.